# Can a single PS Plus subscription be used on two different profiles on the same PS4?

Tags: ps4, psn, playstation-plus

Both my girlfriend and I play on the PS4 at home, so there are 2 profiles on PS4. When we set our profile in PS4, we set the console as the primary console.

Now we want to buy PSN Plus subscription, and I want to know if the same subscription can be used in both profiles, or  only in one.

In case the same subscription can be used in both profiles, how can we set it up? Or is automatic?

Comment: So you got 2 local profiles and 2 different psn profiles? So 2 registered e-mail adresses?

Comment: I have 1 psn4, with 2 profiles (my profile--> Shudy, and my girlfriend --> GIRLFriend), but for the moment no one have any type of suscription.

Comment: You can have several local ps4 accounts but all bind to 1 psn account (which makes sense in your case because you would need just 1 psn+ subscription)

Comment: Ok,lets suppose, I go with my account (Shudy/blahblah@mail.com) and I bought 1 year subs. What has to do my girfiend, to play online etc..? (GirlFriend/gfgfgf@mail.com)

Both accounts are as local profiles in psn4 (Sorry for all these questions, but thats my first time... i alway used xbox360 without subscriptions ^^ )

Comment: I'll make an answer for this give me a sec...

Comment: Ok thanks for it ;) Every day ILove more and more exchange world and his community

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are differences in local accounts and PlayStation Network (PSN) accounts.

A local account is just a name to identify a user on the PS4. 
A PSN account is an email + password combination to that identifies you on Sony's servers.

In your special case let's say you got two local account:

- Shudy
- Girlfriend

both without any linked PSN account. And you got two PSN accounts:

- shudy@example.com (this one got PS-Plus subscription)
- girlfriend@example.com

You can now link **one** PSN account to **any** of your local accounts. But in this example only the local account linked to shudy@example.com will have the PS Plus subscription. So you would have to link both local accounts to shudy@example.com to get PS Plus on both local accounts. But such a link isn't permanent - you can always log off a PSN account and log back in with another one. That's how you can share games between different PS4 systems (it's allowed and possible on three different PS4 systems at the same time).

Comment: both myself *and* my other half have (independent) PSN accounts, but only *I* pay for PS+ - She is still able to play online multiplayer on her account.

Comment: It depends on the game of course, which one you're playing?

Comment: I suggest this change: *But in this example only the local account+(s)+ linked* because I thought that only one local account can use PS Plus.

Answer (score 8):

If the main thing you're concerned about is online multiplayer, then yes, all accounts on a single PS4 can play online if at least one if them has an active PS Plus subscription, and that PS4 console is set as the PS Plus account's "Primary PS4."

From Sony's FAQ:

PlayStation®Plus benefits available to other non-subscribing users on your Primary PS4™:
- Online multiplayer (subject to any parental control settings on sub accounts)
- Play downloaded games purchased with PlayStation®Plus discount
- Play downloaded IGC games

PlayStation®Plus benefits not available to other users on your Primary PS4™:
- Purchasing PlayStation®Plus discounted products from PlayStation Store
- Online game save storage
- Auto patch download
- PlayStation®Plus exclusive early access to game trials

Answer (score 1):

Subscription to PS-Plus is linked to your PSN account, which means that you will only be able to access the features of PS+ on the local playstation account linked to that PSN account.

You will have to buy 2 subscriptions, or just use the same profile as your Girlfriend.

Comment: Thats why i asked for local/psn. As you say, he can link 1 psn to 2 different local accs