# 2 PS3s one profile?

Tags: ps3, psn

So I have a ps3 (which has all my saved games on it) and my boyfriend has a ps3 (that the kids play, I don't have a profile on there yet). Neither of us have a PSN account.
Is there an easy way to have it set up so that I can play on my ps3 (say in the bedroom) and save a game, then 10 mins later play the same game (from the same save point) on his ps3 in the lounge?
Note, most of the games are LEGO, Little Big Planet etc, so I'm assuming they are copy protected, and I'm hoping I don't have to keep transferring data via a flash drive (or would this wipe other profiles on his ps3?)
Thanks in advance

Comment: Aside from transferring to a hard drive PSN is the way to go, problem is that you'll probably need a Playstation Plus subscription to access the Could Saves. i am unsure if games that natively support cloud saves (ie Final Fantasy X/X-2 HD, Atelier Rorona Plus) will allow you to do it without Playstation Plus Subscriptions

Answer (score 3):

I answered a [**similar question**](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/200828/psn-plus-and-2-profiles-in-same-ps4/200831#200831) question a month ago, read this to get the main idea of how the playstation profile system works.

But to complete the question in your special case:

There are 2 ways of sharing savegames between several PlayStation Systems.

1. Use an external hard-drive and copy the savegames you need to it. You would have to repeat that whenever you wanna change the console and some games got "blocked" save-files which means, that you wont be able to copy them on any external drive.
2. PlayStation-Plus (PS+) subscription is a way to sync savegames within Sonys Cloud. If you log into a PS-Account with an active PS+, your savegames will be uploaded so you would be able to use the same account on several systems to up-/download your savegames whenever needed.