# Can two accounts on the same PS4 play on PSN if only one has PlayStation Plus?

Tags: ps4, psn, playstation-plus

My brother is the only one who has a PS Plus membership. Can I play online too (on my own PSN account but on the same console) even if I don't have a membership myself?

Comment: Hi, your question has already been asked and answered at  http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/200828/psn-plus-and-2-profiles-in-same-ps4. If this does not answer your question, try editing your question such that it is different from the linked question

Comment: Yes, you can. I play most of my games from non-Plus account and it works. But it really would be faster for you to launch any game and test for yourself =)