# Linking two Ps4's

Tags: ps4, psn, playstation-plus

I just got my second PS4. My brother and I have the same individual account for each Playstation, so they are linked. On our main PS4 we have had Playstation plus for a year. On our second PS4, it only let's me have the original Playstation plus account, not my brothers account.

**How can we both have Playstation plus on our secondary ps4?**

Comment: Just to clarify I understand the question - You both use the same account, correct?

Comment: You guys share the same PSN account, and want to access it on whichever PS4 you decide to log into from your local account?

Comment: I dont understand the question. ps-plus is bound to an account not a console. Maybe http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/200831/39392 helps?

Answer (score 1):

If you share the same account it will be fine. One PS4 will need to be the primary system, but so long as you both use the same account there won't be any issues. 
If you use separate accounts but use the one account to share games and in particular share PS plus then it may still be possible.

[This](https://nerdburglars.net/docs/playstation-4/playstation-network/primary-ps4-explained/) guide will explain in detail how the primary PS4 system works. The short version is that the primary PS4 allows all users on that PS4 to get the perks. You can log into any secondary PS4 and still have the perks of the user account you are logged in with, but they don't get shared with other users.

Answer (score 0):

PSN+ is tied to the account that has the subscription, and the PS4 that is activated as the primary for that account is the system that benefits from the subscription services.

If you want the benefits of PSN+ on your second PS4 then you will need to make a second subscription to the service with a second account, and that account will need to activate the second PS4 as it's primary.